# Microchip PIC18F45K50 Target Device ID (0x1200) is a valid Device ID but does not match the expected Device ID (0x5c00) as selected

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab

I am in MPLAB 3.65 in Windows 10 trying to load a program onto a Microchip PIC18F45K50. The program builds fine, but the following is the ICD 3 output when I try to load the code:

---

Connecting to MPLAB ICD 3...

Currently loaded firmware on ICD 3
Firmware Suite Version.....01.49.09
Firmware type..............PIC18F

Programmer to target power is enabled - VDD = 3.250000 volts.
****Target Device ID (0x1200) is a valid Device ID but does not match the expected Device ID (0x5c00) as selected.

Device Erased...

Programming...

The following memory area(s) will be programmed:
program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x3d7f
configuration memory
program memory
Address: 0 Expected Value: 41 Received Value: ff
****Failed to program device

---

I'm powering the device from the ICD 3, and using XC8. The debugger self-test is successful. I'm pretty certain I have the USB drivers installed correctly.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Probably the device in your project configuration is not matching the actual device.

Comment: Is this a development board or your own? I ask because the last part "The following memory... Failed to program device" may be related to the programming connections/circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An incorrect ID may indicate, as Eugene Sh mentioned, the device is not a PIC18F45K50. It also may be that the data read back (over PGC/PGD) is corrupted. Wiring between the ICD3 and the chip must be kept reasonably short.

Have you followed section 2.0 of the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41630B.pdf) regarding power? In particular the requirement that VUSB3VS must be connected to either a supply voltage (not VDD for F devices) or a low ESR cap.

Comment: Yeah it turns out my manufacturer sent me the wrong chip. So it goes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In project properties define the device in pull down menu again, because the expected ID of selected device is from **PIC18F4550** and not from **PIC18F45K50**, (similar devices but not the same). :)